# What is the simplest way to share a multi-container app on docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, dockerhub

I have a fully dockerised app with multiple services: frontend, backend, user-service, multiple databases etc...

I orchestrate everything using a `docker-compose.yml` file. I am now trying to share this app with someone who has no CS/coding knowledge so that all they will need to do is pull this app from docker hub and enter the command `docker-compose up` or something similar.

I'm looking into the best way to do this and I'm getting very lost with the docker lexicon of swarms, bundles, stacks, services etc...

What is the best practice for sharing a collection of images started with a docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Put them on Github?

Comment: @Yuankun I considered putting on github or bitbucket, but other members of my team insist it be on docker hub. I think one of the reasons being so that the non programmers don't have to deal with version control semantics (cloning, pulling, branches etc...) Although docker hub is not that different in that respect so not entirely sure why he's so insistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Push the images to Dockerhub (possibly into a private repository).

Give the docker-compose.yml file to whoever needs it (along with an associated .env if needed).

Get them to log in to docker hub (i.e. they'll need a Dockerhub user and access to your images if they are in a private repository)

Run docker-compose up -d

That should be all you need to do, docker-compose should pull the images down and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Is it best practice to push all my images to one private repo or create multiple private repos?

Comment: one image per Docker Hub repo

Comment: There is no "docker-compose file sharing" solution other then just storing it on github and putting info about it in README.md. Then that gets pulled into Docker Hub repos so people can read about your compose file and get them via links.

Comment: I'd have one private repository for multiple images; this means that you only have to grant access once to whoever needs it. If you had one repository per image this would soon end up being difficult to manage from a security point of view.

Comment: This might be a separate question, but does Kitematic support the docker-compose.yml files? My users will be uncomfortable even using the command line to run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: I#d say that's a separate question, I only use the command line myself (for the moment anyway).